# Need addEventListener() bubbling fix

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm testing my function counting mouse position, in which two `addEventListener`s are included. Something goes wrong and I get an alert message each time the mouse is moved, whereas it must be only by clicking, because another listener only helps to count coordinates. I tried `e.stopPropagation()`, but it did not work. Does anyone have an idea how can I fix it

```js
function changeCode(e) {
  document.addEventListener('click', alert('message'), false )
  
}
let posGet = document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  let mousecoords = getMousePos(e);
  
  if (mousecoords.x > -400) {
    
    changeCode(e)
    
  }
}, false );

function getMousePos(e) {
  return { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you add instruction to event listener and add the '()', JS will execute it instantly, that's why it alerted when the mouse moved.

So a solution can be to give it an anonymous function like :

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(){alert('message')}, false )
```

This will give the function as a callback to the event and only execute it when the event is triggered.

But your code has another problem : it will add event listener each time the mouse move and x > -400. This will repeat the intruction each time and you will be stuck with alert() x each time the mouse moved.

to mitigate this you can just add the event listener out of the function.

Or, in my example, the event listener is bound to a specific function, this makes you able to remove it, thus avoiding the repeating eventListener.

```js
function changeCode(e) {
  document.removeEventListener('click', mouseClickHandler, false );
  document.addEventListener('click', mouseClickHandler, false );

  
}
function mouseClickHandler(){
    alert('message');
}

let posGet = document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  let mousecoords = getMousePos(e);
  
  if (mousecoords.x > -400) {
    
    changeCode(e)
    
  }
}, false );

function getMousePos(e) {
  return { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY };
}
```